# How can I pretty print a data frame in Zeppelin/Spark/Scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

I am using Spark 2 and Scala 2.11 in a Zeppelin 0.7 notebook. I have a dataframe that I can print like this:

```
dfLemma.select("text", "lemma").show(20,false)
```

and the output looks like:

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|text                                                                                                                       |lemma                                                                                                                                                                  |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|RT @Dope_Promo: When you and your crew beat your high scores on FUGLY FROG  https://time.com/Sxp3Onz1w8                    |[rt, @dope_promo, :, when, you, and, you, crew, beat, you, high, score, on, FUGLY, FROG, https://time.com/sxp3onz1w8]                                                      |
|RT @axolROSE: Did yall just call Kermit the frog a lizard?  https://time.com/wDAEAEr1Ay                                        |[rt, @axolrose, :, do, yall, just, call, Kermit, the, frog, a, lizard, ?, https://time.com/wdaeaer1ay]                                                                     |
```

I am trying to make the output nicer in Zeppelin, by:

```
val printcols= dfLemma.select("text", "lemma")
println("%table " + printcols)
```

which gives this output:

```
printcols: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [text: string, lemma: array<string>]
```

and a new blank Zeppelin paragraph headed

```
[text: string, lemma: array]
```

Is there a way of getting the dataframe to show as a nicely formatted table?
TIA!

Answer (score 81, accepted):

In Zeppelin you can use `z.show(df)` to show a pretty table. Here's an example:

```
val df = Seq(
  (1,1,1), (2,2,2), (3,3,3)
).toDF("first_column", "second_column", "third_column")

z.show(df)
```

[image]

Comment: Nice. Being unaware of this, I had written my own pretty print function (leveraging ``%table``) for pyspark. I cannot find this anywhere in the documentation, however...

Comment: @TwUxTLi51Nus It's true the docs are not very good for this part. You can find some info about the ZeppelinContext [here](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/latest/interpreter/spark.html#zeppelincontext) and in the code ([here](https://github.com/apache/zeppelin/blob/branch-0.7/spark/src/main/java/org/apache/zeppelin/spark/ZeppelinContext.java)) you can see all available functions. Also, in the notebook you can check using ctrl+space on the z variable.

Comment: ctrl + space does not work for me, however (in python) ``dir(z)`` does.

Comment: @TwUxTLi51Nus Nice. About the hotkey, maybe "ctrl + ."  works?

Comment: Works great, thanks! Can the number of rows be limited?

Comment: @schoon you're welcome! You can limit the number of rows with a second parameter: `z.show(df, 10)`

Comment: I always find a more complex way. I did this: z.show(dfLemma.select("racist", "lemma").limit(20)). Will try yours.

Comment: Asked a bit more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45026919/how-can-i-pretty-print-a-wrappedarray-in-zeppelin-spark-scala).

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread, but just in case it helps...

The below was the only way that I could take show a portion of the `df`. Trying to add a second parameter to `.show()` as suggested in the comments is throwing an error.

`z.show(df.limit(10))`

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following line in your notebook will add a horizontal scroll bar when you use `.show()` method. It is similar to the jupyter notebook styling trick.

```
%sh echo "%html <style>.text.plainTextContent {white-space: pre;}<style>"
```

Something like this:
[image]