# How can I pretty print a wrappedarray in Zeppelin/Spark/Scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44946620/how-can-i-pretty-print-a-data-frame-in-zeppelin-spark-scala/44947118?noredirect=1#comment76874375_44947118) question I was told how to print a dataframe using zeppelin's z.show command. This works well except for 'WrappedArray' appearing in the lemma column: 
[image]

I have tried this:

```
z.show(dfLemma.select(concat_ws(",", $"lemma")))
```

but it just gave me a list of words, not nicely formatted and I also want the racist column in my output.
Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: How do you expect this column's data to be shown?

Comment: capture your selections in a variable and then transform it into a suitable format. Now you can print the transformed selection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a suggestion for formatting your array column:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.Column
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import sqlContext.implicits._

val df = Seq(
  (1, Array("An", "Array")), (2, Array("Another", "Array"))
).toDF("first", "second")

def formatArrayColumn(arrayColumn: Column): Column = {
  concat(lit("["), concat_ws(", ", arrayColumn), lit("]")).as(s"format(${arrayColumn.expr})")
}

val result = df.withColumn("second", formatArrayColumn($"second"))

z.show(result)
```

Which results in:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Daniel but it just outputs a big string, (also when I select just two columns): import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.concat_wsformatArrayColumn: (arrayColumn: org.apache.spark.sql.Column)org.apache.spark.sql.Columnresult: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [racist: boolean, contributors: string ... 27 more fields]%table racist lemmafalse [rt, @dope_promo, :, when, you, and, you, crew, beat

Comment: @schoon So please be clear in your question about what you are expecting as output for this column.

Comment: I was expecting what you have produced. But all I get is a long string of text.

Comment: @schoon can you update your question with what you tried, what was the result and what you expect?

Comment: Never mind, it was because I  had another show statement. When I got rid of it it worked! Thanks!