# Vizualization with zeppelin using cassandra and spark

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, apache-zeppelin

I'm new with zeppelin, but it look like interesting.
I'd like to do some visualization with cassandra's data reading with spark within zeppelin. But I can't do it, yet!

This is my code:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra._
import org.apache.spark.sql
val createDDL = """CREATE TEMPORARY VIEW keyspaces9
 USING org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra
 OPTIONS (
 table "foehis",
 keyspace "tfm",
 pushdown "true")"""
spark.sql(createDDL) 
spark.sql("SELECT hoclic,hodtac,hohrac,hotpac FROM keyspaces").show
```

And I get:

```
res41: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = []
+------+--------+------+------+
|hoclic|  hodtac|hohrac|hotpac|
+------+--------+------+------+
|  1011|10180619|   510|  ENPR|
|  1011|20140427|   800|  ANDE|
|  1011|20140427|   800|  ANDE|
|  1011|20170522|  1100|  ANDE|
|  1011|20170522|  1100|  ANDE|
....
```

But I don't have the ability to make a viz

How do I convert that data into a table for zeppelin?

Comment: Looks like this would answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44946620/how-can-i-pretty-print-a-data-frame-in-zeppelin-spark-scala

Answer (score 1):

Register the DataFrame as a Table using `df.registerTempTable`. 
In your case, register 'keyspaces' dataframe as table and then you can execute the SQL queries on the table and create visualizations.

Sample code:
[image]